# Creating a Metro app which updates itself Periodically and not placed in lock screen

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

As mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx):

It seems that `a background task will only run using a TimeTrigger if the user has placed your app on the lock screen`.

So, how can I create a `Calendar` like app without background task? I mean an app which:

1. updates its tile *Periodically* (e.g. once a day)?
2. updates its tile even when it's not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule periodic updates of an application's tile without being on the start screen.  See this article for [Notification Delivery methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh779721.aspx). Then, once the app is launched, you could update the calendar in general.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a maintenance trigger.  These triggers will only fire once every two hours and will only fire if the machine is on AC power.  When your trigger runs, you could look for upcoming appointments and create scheduled toast notifications.

```
var scheduledToast = new Windows.UI.Notifications.ScheduledToastNotification(toastXml, startTime);
```

You could update the tile as well with a ScheduledTileNotifcation() call.  Unfortunately, I don't think there  is a way to remove a notification so if the user deletes an appointment prior to the scheduled notification, I don't think you can remove it.  I'm looking deeper into that and will comment here if I find an answer.

However, I would think for a calendar app you would want it to use a TimeTrigger and be placed on the lock screen since I would want to receive appointment reminders at any time and regardless of being plugged in or not.

Is there a reason you do not want to use the TimeTrigger?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Calendar was just an example, and it seems that it's not a very good one. Actually the main reason I do not wanna use TimeTrigger is that I do not wanna ask user for background permission.

Comment: @JeffBrand you can removed scheduled notifications via GetScheduledTileNotifications/RemoveFromSchedule.  

MBZ - on the surface Periodic Notifications would fit the bill BUT requires another service to update the tile XML that your 'dormant' application would then poll on an up-to daily basis.  Still not a perfect scenario for you, since that other service is tantamount to a background trigger

Comment: @JimO'Neil. I thought there was something to accomplish it, just couldn't seem to find it with a quick skim.  Thanks!